# Angular/Rxjs run store (ngrx) calls synchronously

Tags: angular, async-await, rxjs, ngrx

I need to perform an action, after retrieving 2 objects from my store (ngrx), so, I need both calls to have responded before performing my action, like this :

```
const item1$: Observable<Item> = this._store$.select(
  ItemStoreSelectors.selectItemById(this.id1)
);

const item2$: Observable<Item> = this._store$.select(
  ItemStoreSelectors.selectItemById(this.id2)
);

let item1: Item;
item1$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe((item: Item) => {
  item1 = item;
});

let item2: Item;
item2$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe((item: Item) => {
  item2 = item;
});

// here, items might not have been initialized
doSomething(item1, item2);
```

I tried to look out for a solution in rxjs with switchMap, mergeMap, etc, but couldn't apply it to my needs. I think I found a solution doing async/await, but I'm not sure this is a good practice.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: use combineLatest https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html

Comment: or depending on the case... `forkJoin`.

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm gonna look into that, thank you, I've already tried I think but couldn't get it to work with my case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refactor into the following code :

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';

const item1$: Observable<Item> = this._store$.select(
  ItemStoreSelectors.selectItemById(this.id1)
);

const item2$: Observable<Item> = this._store$.select(
  ItemStoreSelectors.selectItemById(this.id2)
);

forkJoin([item1$.pipe(take(1)), item2$.pipe(take(1))])
   .subscribe(([item1,item2])=>doSomething(item1,item2));
```

Comment: thank you it looks awesome, so if I understand well, subscribe will only fire when both items have been fired ?

Comment: Correct, forkJoin creates an observable that emits the last value of its sources after all of them completed.

Answer (score 1):

combineLatest will be triggered every time one of the observable fire, if this is what you want, try this out:

```
item1$: Observable<Item> = this._store$.select(
  ItemStoreSelectors.selectItemById(this.id1)
);

item2$: Observable<Item> = this._store$.select(
  ItemStoreSelectors.selectItemById(this.id2)
);

result$: Observable<any> = combineLatest(this.item1$, this.item2$, this.doSomething());
```

Comment: thank you as well, I'm gonna look into the difference between combineLatest and forkJoin as @Jota. Toledo answered but I think it doesn't answer completely to my needs because I need a pipe(take(1))

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use withLatestFrom in an effect. Something like this

```
@Effect()
  myAction$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<MyAction>(MyActionTypes.MyAction),
    withLatestFrom(this.store.select(mySelector)),
    withLatestFrom(this.store.select(myOtherSelector)),
    exhaustMap(([[action, item1], item2]) =>
      this.myService.myRequest(/*...*/)
      .pipe(
        map(myResult => new GetResultSuccess(myResult)),
        catchError(error => of(new GetResultFailure(error))),
      ),
    ),
  );
```